# React Router Link from another component wont work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

so i had a navbar component that has a `<Link></Link>` inside of it the problem in i couldn't use that link for the router (it wont refresh) when i clicked on it although the link appears on the URL but it didn't refresh

here's the code

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import {BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom'
    import Route from 'react-router-dom/Route'
    import Nav from './Nav'
    
    
    
    export class App extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <div className="App">
          <Router>
            
            {/* NAVBAR */}
            <Nav /> 
    
            <Route path="/" exact render={
              () => <h1>home</h1>
            }/>
            <Route path="/about" exact render={
              () => <h1>about</h1>
            }/>
            <Route path="/author" exact render={
              () => <h1>author</h1>
            }/>
          </Router>
        </div>
        )
      }
    }
    
    export default App
```

and here's the navbar code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import styles from './Nav.module.css'
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

export class Nav extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <div className={styles.nav}>
                <div className="container">
                    <div className={styles.navgrid}>
                            <img className={styles.image} src="/img/actualLogo@1x.svg" alt="?"/>
                            <ul className={styles.ultest}>
                                <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
                                <li><Link to="/updates">Updates</Link></li>
                                <li><Link to="/author">Author</Link></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div> 
                </div>
                </div>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}

export default Nav
```

I'm assuming it's because it's not on the same `<Router></Router>` but does anyone have a way to make this work?

Comment: `import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom'`
Your import should look this way. Remove the Individual `Route` import and update import with the one mentioned before.

Comment: This might help: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a new `<Router>`, which has no defined `<Route>` elements within it.  Remove that router:

```
export class Nav extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className={styles.nav}>
                <div className="container">
                    <div className={styles.navgrid}>
                        <img className={styles.image} src="/img/actualLogo@1x.svg" alt="?"/>
                        <ul className={styles.ultest}>
                            <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
                            <li><Link to="/updates">Updates</Link></li>
                            <li><Link to="/author">Author</Link></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Each component doesn't need its own `<Router>`, as long as they're all contained within (descendants of) the one defined in `<App>`.

Comment: Exactly, just remove the router from Nav and you are good to go.